# 'object not found' error when knitting to HTML in RMarkdown

Tags: r, rstudio, knitr, r-markdown

I am testing RMarkdown for the first time and am running into an issue when trying to knit anything to HTML. For example: I attempt to knit the following to HTML

```
# Say Hello to markdown

Markdown is an **easy to use** format for writing reports. It resembles what you naturally write every time you compose an email. In fact, you may have already used markdown *without realizing it*. These websites all rely on markdown formatting

* [Github](www.github.com)
* [StackOverflow](www.stackoverflow.com)
* [Reddit](www.reddit.com)
```

The above is taken directly from an example on this page: http://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/articles_intro.html

However, when I use the Knit to HTML button I receive this error:

```
Error: object 'a' not found
Execution halted
```

Maybe this is a simple question that I am not seeing the answer to, but I do not know how to interpret and correct this error message, as nowhere in my Markdown file am I calling any sort of object 'a'. Thank you for your assistance!

Comment: I use knitr to LaTeX, but your example above is not a markdown chunk.

Comment: Can you elaborate? It seems like the rmarkdown article I linked knits this to HTML without any additional code or input. Am I missing something there?

Comment: I attempted to add a YAML header, did not change the error message

Comment: I copied and pasted and this error was not reproducible for me.

Comment: Just as an update. I was able to achieve what I was looking to do by using the rmarkdown::render() command on my .rmd file. Still not sure why I was not able to use the knit button on the RStudio toolbar though.

Comment: maybe you shoulld provide all ur rmarkdown `.Rmd` script. The content u post just text and do not contain any chunk or something else. Edit please and others can check in more detail